# A syntax error appears when launching the application on nest

Tags: node.js, nestjs

```
[16:00:15] Starting compilation in watch mode...
[16:00:18] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

/Users/kirill/Documents/Документы — MacBook Pro - Customer/IT/additional courses/nest.js/educ-project/node_modules/@nestjs/common/file-stream/streamable-file.js:34 this.stream ??= bufferOrReadStream; ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:16) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:27) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kirill/Documents/Документы — MacBook Pro - Customer/IT/additional courses/nest.js/educ-project/node_modules/@nestjs/common/file-stream/index.js:4:22) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
```

I tried to fix the situation by correcting this error in the source code, but it is not an error, and this expression is repeated in other modules.

Answer (score 0):

that's due to your nodejs version

Make sure you're using node v16+ if you want to use nestjs v10, as per the migration guide

Otherwise you'll need to downgrade nestjs to v9